# Java, Dropbox-API : Get a list of folder-names available on account with path.

Tags: java, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am working on a Spring-MVC project in which I am using Dropbox for users to upload files. For that, I would like to get a list of folders, so the user can choose where to upload the file and I will maintain a record of that.

How can I do that with dropbox-java apis? I tried some code, but it is not showing me the 2 folders that I have created in my dropbox account. Any help would be nice.

Code :

```
  @Override
    public List<String> getListOfFolders(Long groupAccountId) {
        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            GroupAccount groupAccount = this.groupAccountService.getGroupById(groupAccountId);
            Person person = this.personService.findPersonByUsername(groupAccount.getAdminUsername());
            if (person.isDropbox()) {
                DbxClient client = new DbxClient(config, person.getDropboxAccessToken());
                DbxEntry entry = client.getMetadata("/");
                if (entry instanceof DbxEntry.Folder) {
                    DbxEntry.Folder folder = (DbxEntry.Folder)entry;
                    stringList.add(folder.toString());
                    System.out.println(folder.toString());
                }
            }
            return stringList;
        } catch (DbxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return stringList;
        }
    }
```

Output :

```
Folder("/", iconName="folder", mightHaveThumbnail=false)
```

Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: The `getMetadata` method is the right one to use to list the contents of a path, or you can use `getDelta` if you need recursive listing. If you're not seeing the results you expect make sure you're linked to the right account. Also, if your app is registered for the "app folder" permission, you'll only see items in the app's app folder (created by default under /Apps for the English localization).

Comment: Also, your code doesn't seem to do any enumeration at all. (I don't see a loop anywhere.) I believe there should be a `children` property if you cast to `[DbxEntry.WithChildren](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.7.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxEntry.WithChildren.html)`? Not 100% sure.

Comment: @Greg : The getMetaData method does not return a list to iterate and the getDelta method cannot be used with For-each. Can you give me any example of how to get list of folders because I have spent quite a lot of time searching and cannot find any. Secondly, it is the right account as the insert-file is performing correctly with the account I have linked.

Comment: @smarx : THe URL you gave is a 404. I know I am there is enumeration as  I cannot find a method which will give me something with which I can enumerate. If I use getDelta, then IDE complains that for-each not applicable to DbxDelta<DbxEntry> . Can you please give me an example of how to achieve this task. Thank you.

Comment: Trying the URL again, though it looks like this is identical to my previous comment: http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.7.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxEntry.WithChildren.html

Comment: Did you try the cast I suggested?

Comment: Oh, you need to call `getMetadataWithChildren` to get back an object with a `children` member. You'll then enumerate over that (e.g. `for (DbxEntry child : metadata.children)`). See https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/master/examples/web-file-browser/src/com/dropbox/core/examples/web_file_browser/DropboxBrowse.java#L75-L83 for an example.

Comment: @smarx : The example helped. Thanks. I can get it now. Please post an answer. Thank you.